# Create MSG files by automating Outlook Express with Visual Studio Express

Tags: interop, outlook, devexpress

I'm wondering if I can use outlook express to create .MSG files using Visual Studio Express

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "MSG" files, do you mean the Outlook MSG format or the Firefox MSG format?

Either way, it is doubtful. IIRC, OE was written in C, so it's not like you can set any references to any dlls.

Sorry,
Dave